# A sed script to fix an invalid RFC2822 email header

Tags: sed

I have emails coming into a processing system, and some of them have started coming in with an invalid blank line splitting the email headers, like this:

```
Date: Thu, 7 Mar 2013 22:24:44 +0000
Message-ID: <86A1035194F72547A2979A7767CD3BAF35485B8D@QTS-MB02.ecicloud.com>
References: <C0DA0966847B31409025BBD9A70187DA35399D17@QTS-MB02.ecicloud.com>

Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
```

The blank line in the middle is invalid and causes problems for downstream programs.

I'd like to come up with a simple `sed` script to fix any occurences specifically of `Accept-Language:.*` preceded by a blank line, so that the blank line is eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all blank lines in a lines in file with `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' file
```

Delete blank line from the start of the file upto the line starting `Content-Language`:

```
sed -i '1,/^Content-Language/{/^\s*$/d}' file
```

Comment: I don't want to delete all blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^[ \t]*$/ {N;/\nAccept-Language: en-US$/! P;D;}' FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really look at the formail and procmail commands for processing email. See http://www.procmail.org/ and http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/formail1.html.